# Replace whitespace in pandas dataframe with 0 in all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a dataframe, df with 15 columns. These columns contains scores of products. I want to replace all blank values(white spaces) here with 0. How to proceed here.

Comment: Please show examples of you code

Comment: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `dataframe.replace()`:

```
df=df.replace({'':0,' ':0,float('NaN'):0})
```

OR

```
df=df.replace(r'\s*',0,regex=True).fillna(0)
```

Sample Dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[56,42,'',' ',float('NaN')],'col2':[float('NaN'),45,'',' ',89]})
```